# Java NullException

Tags: exception

I'm unable to find the solution of this Null Exception.Why this is happening & what is its solution.This is constructor & I'm assigning resultset values to jtable.

```
    public Show_search(ResultSet rst){
       ResultSet rs = rst;
       int row = 0;
       try {
          while(rs.next()){
             System.out.println("ROW:"+row);
             System.out.println(rs.getString("l_name"));
             tbl.setValueAt(rs.getString("l_name"), row, 1);//Line 33
             row++;
          }
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Claim_summary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }
```

This is Exception.

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Gui.Show_search.<init>(Show_search.java:33)
```

Comment: Do you mean NullPointerException? Which line is line 33 in your constructor? (Please add java tag to your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the Exception tells you on which line it comes from: 33!
And there you cal tbl.setValueAt, obviously is tbl null!!!

Where does tbl get initialized? is it in the scope of your class (because it is not in the scope of your method)?

you need to initialize it or give it to the method as a parameter!!

It is always good practice to check for null:

```
if (table != null)
   do somthing;
else
   do onother thing;
```

Comment: yes tbl is null but I think it does't matter either it is null or not.

Comment: I've found the problem.I was using resultset.next() in calling as well as called function and resultset contained only one result.So this was the exception

Comment: when it comes to setValueAt on tbl and tbl is null, then you will get the NullPointerException, see edit